# How Valmiki existed 5000 BCE and 500 BCE?

Tags: ramayana, rama, valmiki

It is widely accepted that

- Lord Rama existed 5000 BCE
- Sage Valmiki wrote Ramayana epic in 500 BCE
- Valmiki taught Lav and Kush(twin sons of Lord Rama)

The problem is pretty clear. Is it that westerners came up with wrong date?

Comment: "It is widely accepted that" - accepted by whom ? All current acharyas accept that Rama lived towards end of Treta Yuga. Kali Yuga started in 3102 BC. Dwapara Yuga was before Kali. And Treta was before Dwapara. Those dates you read are written by westerners.

Comment: And it wasn't the recent Treta Yuga. We live in the 28th Kali Yuga and Ramayana occured in the 24th Treta Yuga.

Comment: @Wikash_, correct. just like Jesus is a mythology and Hitler will be a mythology in a few hundred years time.

Comment: @ram no Hitler will remain a fact since we have lots of proof that he existed. Yes I agree Jesus is mythology.

Comment: @Wikash_, there are already many people who deny the holocaust. just give it time.

Comment: @ram  Don't bother . Its very clear that Ramayana and Mahabharata are Itihasa(history) but some people will keep on using the term mythology either due to ignorance or sometimes due to some prejudice against Hinduism.

Comment: @Wikash_ Please stop posting off-topic comments. It serves no purpose except to please your ego.

Comment: @Gabe it is not offtopic. I helped answer the question.

Comment: @ram I want to believe that the numbers come from westerners, It seems to be the only answer... although we can say that modern technique gives us that number and not westerners... but I am looking for a solution that can bridge the gap between modern science and or vedas. I dont want to keep them apart, I want an answer as why they may be wrong or If their number match maybe our perspective of looking the numbers may be wrong. It just makes a lot sense that lord rama existed 5000 BCE then imagining that he existed lacs of years ago...

Comment: if we want to prove that lord Ram is not mythology but history we must simply say that you are wrong, that would be the conversation ender... they would keep thinking its mythology we would think its history everyone will remain where they are. It will become a fruitless conversation.

Comment: @ShreyanshuMalviya, yes, it will be a fruitless conversation until they get more spiritually advanced. there are people today who think Jesus was a myth and not actual person. No point wasting time with those folks. There are people today who think the Holocaust was a myth, that moon landing was fake, that earth is flat. No point arguing with them.